# Terraform error: Provider produced inconsistent final plan when expanding the plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, bamboo

I got an error when create iam policy for ec2 role via bamboo pipeline.

> Error: Provider produced inconsistent final plan when expanding the plan for aws_iam_policy.this[xx] to include new values learned so far during apply, provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" produced an invalid new value for policy: was cty.StringVal(xx), but now cty.StringVal(xx). This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own issue tracker. It was good when ran terraform from local machine but the error occurred when deployed via bamboo pipeline.

Versions on my local machine:
Terraform v1.2.5
AWS v4.29.0

I tried to specify the aws provider version=4.29.0 but got another error:

> "Provider requirements cannot be satisfied by locked dependencies".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to write about this types of errors to the AWS provider [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues)

Also, I suggest to double check your terraform code, maybe a little bit simplify it.

About:

```
Provider requirements cannot be satisfied by locked dependencies
```

looks like your forget to run terraform init after provider version changing

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your advice. I had also posted on AWS provider github and haven't received any comments yet. Yes, we did have a "terraform init" step in our bamboo file and still got errors. But when ran terraform apply from local machine, it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is regarding tags use tags_all instead tag i.e

```
tags = {
     Environment = "Prod"
     Owner       = "Bits Lovers"
     Goal        = "Biggest Blog about DevOps"
   }
###use below

tags_all = {
     Environment = "Prod"
     Owner       = "Bits Lovers"
     Goal        = "Biggest Blog about DevOps"
   }
```